# Safe way of making comment section in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, comments

Good day!

Today am working on comment section for my site. I know that its not so hard to make working comment section but i want to make it safe and prevent sql injection.

What are your suggestions, how i should make it and what should I watch out for ?

I will post here my idea  so you can tell me which part is unsafe .

Lets suppose u need to be registered and logged in to comment.

```
<html>
<head>
require 'connect.inc.php';
require 'function.php';
</head>
<body>

<?php
if(loggedin()){
$id = $_SESSION['user_id']; //loggedin function check if user is logged in

if(isset($_POST['comment_button'])){
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments  VALUES('','$id','$comment')");
}
?>

<form>
Comment:<br>
<textarea name='comment'></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="comment_button" value="Login"/>
</form>

<?php 
}else{header('location: index.php');
} ?>

</body>
</html>
```

This is some basic idea , please note that am novice in all of this so dont  be surprised if u see something bad in this code above . Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reframed some of the part.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <?php
   require 'connect.inc.php';
   require 'function.php';
 ?>
 </head>
 <body>

 <?php
 if(loggedin())
 {
    $id = $_SESSION['user_id']; //loggedin function check if user is logged in

    if(isset($_POST['comment_button']))
    {
      $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'mysampledb');

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
      exit();
    }

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO comments VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', '', '$id', '$comment');   // bind to the parameter

    // escape the POST data for added protection
    $comment = isset($_POST['comment'])
      ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['comment'])
      : '';

   /* execute prepared statement */
   $stmt->execute();

   printf("%d Comment added successfully.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

  /* close statement and connection */
  $stmt->close();

  /* close connection */
  $mysqli->close();

}
?>

<form>
Comment:<br>
<textarea name='comment'></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="comment_button" value="Login"/>
</form>

<?php 
}else{header('location: index.php');
} ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should replace MySQL keywords in your $comment variable before pass it to the query string. Use filter_input or mysql_real_escape_string functions to prevent injections. Altrough, you can use another ways to do the SQL part, which is more secure.

Answer (score 0):

```
$comment=filter_input(INPUT_POST,"comment",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

more info on this [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filter_input.asp)